# Novice: Cakephp2 conditions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hi I'm new to cakephp2 and mysql and I'm here to find some tips and help.

The problem is that I've set the value as 0 to store it in the database:

```
('data'=>0)
```

I made a function that will check if the data is zero or not like:

```
if($data[0]['data']===0).
```

I want to compare the data from the database that has been stored as the int  with 0 , however, this does not work.

Sorry for my bad English, to make it simple I want to compare the data from the database with a int in cakephp2/php, if comparing with 0 should I use is_null,empty or use just === 0  for simple comparison?

Comment: Try using `var_dump` on the `$data[0]['data']` variable. I have a suspicion that it will be a string, not an integer. In which case, the strict equality statement you are using (`===`) will be comparing `'0'` (a string) to `0` (an integer) and will therefore be returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( $data[0]['data'] == 0 ){ //equal to zero

}
```

OR

```
if( $data[0]['data'] != 0 ){ //Not equal to zero

}else{ // equal to zero

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this:

```
if( (int) $data[0]['data'] === 0){
    //your code here
}
```

As stated by Scopey in the comments you probably returned a string '0', not the integer 0.